# phantomjs not loading instagram and pintersest webpages

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, phantomjs, instagram, pinterest

I'm using PhantomJS 2.1.1 in python 2.7.12 under Ubuntu Server 16.04.1, with Display from pyvirtualdisplay

PhantomJS is unable to load instagram interactive dom pages (https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/). The page code should be within

```
<span id="react-root"></span>
```

but it remains empty.

Instagram pages are correctly loaded with PhantomJS 2.1.1 in python 2.7.10 under Mac OS X 10.11.6; PhantomJS under Ubuntu Server can correctly load many other website (twitter, tumblr etc), so I guess that there's some missing module in Ubuntu Server but can't understand which one.

It can't neither load https://www.pinterest.com/login/ but this page is correctly loaded using simply curl.

Could someone help?
Thank you.

Here's the python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pytvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0,size=(800,600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.set_window_size(800, 600)
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
```

or

```
browser.get('https://www.pinterest.com/login/')
```

the ghostdriver.log

```
[INFO  - 2016-09-12T16:08:37.057Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 49739
[INFO  - 2016-09-12T16:08:37.933Z] Session [2a14fc60-7903-11e6-a755-53e4799f55f3] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2016-09-12T16:08:37.933Z] Session [2a14fc60-7903-11e6-a755-53e4799f55f3] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2016-09-12T16:08:37.933Z] Session [2a14fc60-7903-11e6-a755-53e4799f55f3] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.1.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"linux-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2016-09-12T16:08:37.934Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 2a14fc60-7903-11e6-a755-53e4799f55f3
```

---

Update:
installing phantomjs with

```
sudo apt-get install phantomjs
```

it correctly loads the entire page. But this package is missing some important third-party dependencies (such as find_element Atom).

installing phantomjs with

```
npm install phantomjs-prebuilt
```

it doesn't correctly load the page (even if it has got all third-party Atoms).

Is there a way to use the executable installed with apt-get and third-party Atoms installed by npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

I solved compiling phantomjs on Ubuntu Server directly from git repository.
So maybe the pre-compiled binaries are not complete.

Details here: http://phantomjs.org/build.html